# Select all words from string except last (PowerShell)

Tags: arrays, powershell, split

So what I am trying to achieve is selecting all words from a given string, except the last one.
So I have a few strings;

```
On The Rocks
The Rocks
Major Bananas
```

I want to select all words, except the last one from every string.
I figured out I could use split() to take every word as separate. Though I can't figure it out any further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how I might do something like this.

```
$Sample = "String sample we can use"
$Split = $Sample.Split(" ")
[string]$split[0..($Split.count-2)]
```

Comment: It's better to join on spaces explicitly, `$split[0..($Split.count - 2)] -join " "`, as it clearly shows what your intention is. (If not, then why didn't you use `$Sample.Split()`)?

Answer (score 15):

```
$string.SubString(0, $string.LastIndexOf(' '))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `..` operator works great, but when working with pipes, you can use the `select` cmdlet (alias for `Select-Object`) instead.
Here's how you can remove items from an array by using the `select` cmdlet.

```
PS> "On The Rocks", "The Rocks", "Major Bananas" |
foreach { write-host $($_ -split ' ' | select -skiplast 1) }
On The
The
Major
PS>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$test -replace "\S*\s*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the last word even if there are trailing spaces. It also preserves multiple spaces between words, and removes spaces before the last word.

```
'this   is   a    test ' -replace '^(.+\b)\s+\S+\s*','$1'
```

It doesn't remove the last word if the string is a single word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string -replace '^(.+)\b.+$','$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but useful. I found use of `-skiplast` more logical/readable.
(noticed it's also been mentioned by @mrsauravsahu)

```
"Hello world skip-me".Split(" ") | Select -skiplast 1
```

#Output: "Hello world"

Note:  Remember split() returns Array.